# How to show page of current user by id

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'v implemented user's page using PHP and MySQl improved, but at the moment the user is the only one, who can see his page(and only if logged in). How to implement, that other users can see his page. User has `id`, which is shown him in the url address like this :

```
  header("Location:http://website/page.php?id={$_SESSION['id']}");
```

How to make such system, when anyone opens `http://website/page.php?id=1`and this or that data and functionality is shown depending on whether it be the logged owner of the page or other user. I guess, that I should get id from url and work with it. How can I do this or how must be such basic things implemented?

Some additional php code (not sure, if it helps)

```
<?php
     session_start();
    include ("bd.php");
    if ( isset( $_SESSION['login'] ) ) {
       $login    = $_SESSION['login'];

      }

    else{

         exit("You are not logged in");
    }

?>

// html code
```

So, the general question is how to build a basic system of naming pages. For example, I go to website/page.php?id=3  and see page of user with id=3, and if I go to website/page.php?id=5 I will see page of user with id=5. How to get id from url?

Comment: Keep in mind that modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) come with some sort of [authentication system](http://laravel.com/docs/security) built-in, so managing access control for a multi-user system is a solved problem. Writing your own is considerably harder and more error-prone than using an off-the-shelf one.

Comment: @tadman but it's anyway important to understand how it works

Comment: From an academic perspective, sure. A framework serves as an excellent example of how to do it if you're curious about the inner workings. If you do it yourself you will get it wrong, probably very wrong unless you've used a modern framework before. Think in terms of top-down, not bottom-up. Do you know the quantum wave function of an electron? Do you know how silicon atoms arrange themselves into crystals? Do you know how a transistor works? How a NAND gate functions? What a flip-flop is? That's a deep hole to go down, and almost all of it is irrelevant to making an authentication system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing there is code in your page that relies on `$_SESSION['id']` to figure out which user page to show. Instead use `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: If it's a different user? He doesn't know what is my id in my session.  But he can know it by url and script will show my data to a different user by id from this url. How to get this id from url for other users ? Or is this implemented other way?

Comment: @vinand that is exactly what dan08 is showing you.  In your URL you have page.php?id=7272    then in the page instead of using the SESSION use the GET variable  .  To allow a user to edit his own page.  Allowed edits only when the $_GET['id'] and $_SESSION['id'] are the same.

Comment: @greg_diesel I have finally understood

Answer (score 1):

From what I've understand you want to create a profile page for users and to show specific data if the current user is viewing his own profile.

That's how you should approach this task:

1. You need to have a User table in the database that will contain the user_id and other additional information as you need.
2. Create a login page and save the user & password (encrypted and salted of course) in the session/cookie.
3. when creating the profile check if the the current user is viewing this page with the user & password from the cookie/session you've just created.

Comment: I'v already implemented everything you pointed. I want to give other users ability to see the page of user(for example, with id=1).  But address website/page/php/id=3 is only address which user with id=3 can see. Other users  must have ability to write this address in url and to open the page of user with id=3.

Comment: @Vinand Can you edit your post with the code of the profile page? so we could see what you did wrong.

Comment: I have edited. Also recommend to read my comment to dan08 answer. Possibly I am describing wrong, and such basic thing is done differently

Comment: @Vinand, you should get the id from the $_GET variable instead from the $_SESSION.
also where are you querying the database? I cant see that part of the code.